# angular installation failed in office proxy

Tags: angular, proxy, installation, npm-install, corporate-policy

I am getting below error while trying to install angular CLI.

Below snap for office proxy:

[image]

This snap for client proxy:

[image]

Please help any one..

Comment: Try command `npm i -g @angular/cli@latest`

Comment: Do you have office proxy with you currently the url and port infact?

Comment: i have office proxy url and port.

Answer (score 1):

We also had similar issues in our office proxy. Then what we did, we added the proxy to the `.npmrc` file with this command:

```
npm config set proxy http://username:password@proxyurl:port
npm config set http_proxy http://username:password@proxyurl:port
npm config set https_proxy https://username:password@proxyurl:port
```

and it all worked for us.